Condition $A^2+B^2\neq 0$ for conic sections?
In general, a conic section can be described by
$$
Ax^2+By^2+Cx+Dy+E=0
$$
with $A^2+B^2\neq 0$.
Why do we need the condition $A^2+B^2\neq 0$?

It should be $By^2$, not $Bx^2$. You're also missing the $Fxy$ term. As for your answer, since $A^2 + B^2 \geq 0$ with equality only when $A=B=0$, but if that happens this no longer remains a conic

In my notes there is no further term like $Fxy$.

I see..without that this isn't the full form of a conic. Are you familiar with the various conic forms?

That condition ensures you don't have a line. Assuming $A$ and $B$ are real, the only way for $A^2 +B^2 = 0$ is if both $A$ and $B$ are $0$ which, according to your equation defining conic sections, would lead to a line ($Cx + Dy + E = 0$).
(If you have the extra $xy$ term usually found in the definition of a conic section, you can recover some conic sections without $A$ and $B$.)
